# Cmder quake hotkey not working

Tags: hotkeys, conemu

I updated Cmder to newer version, and now when I open cmder I get notification in tray, that WIN + ~ can't be registered as hotkey for re-sizing. Anyone knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Show exact message. With screenshot preferable.

Comment: Added screenshot. This is only error I get.

Comment: 1. The real message differs from mentioned by you. 2. https://conemu.github.io/en/OldBuild.html and 3. The hotkey is registered by another application, exactly as message says.

Comment: I used old build with shortcut, and than I updated. Now new application can't replace shortcut because of old. That's what I said. Do you know how can I manually replace?

Comment: I gave you a link. All there.

Comment: Not working, I already have newest version. Like I said, I did manual update.

Comment: Man, have you read the link I posted? Latest version is not 150513.

Comment: I am not using conemu, but cmder variant, thats why this link is no use to me. Look here https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder.

Comment: cmder is not a "program", it's a starter for ConEmu + third-party software.

Comment: I updated conemu but roblem persists. Others reported it too on github.

Comment: Issue ID? Updated screenshot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this because, Cmder and Ditto (or any other application) are using the same shortcut key.

Following steps fixed this issue in my case.

1. Start Cmder.
2. Win + Alt + P
3. Go to the search field: Ctl + F
4. Search for "macros"
5. Now, Change the Hotkey for "Minimize/Restore". Refer to this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Perfect I too had issue with ctrl+` used by ditto, but changed and it works like a charm.